# Extracting rang data from a file ,saving each range to a separate file

Tags: perl

I have been pulling my hair out for 4 days now i still not this to work .I i have to log file and i am i am trying to extracting rang data from the log file and save each range to a separate file. How can i  extract rang data from the log file and save each range to a separate file.

```
 #! /usr/bin/perl/ 
   use warnings;
    use strict;

    my $outdir   = "/home/lord-ivan/Soures_Code/Perl/projects/EJ/Queue/";  
    my $somefile = "/home/lord-ivan/Soures_Code/Perl/projects/Data/EJDATA.LOG";  
    my $count = 0;
    my $spew  = 0;
    my $out;

    open (my $fh, "<  $somefile" ) or die "Could not open file '$somefile' $!";   
    print "$somefile open\n";  

    while (<$fh>) {
        if (/TRANSACTION STARTED/) {
            open($out, '>', "${outdir}TRANSACTION$count.txt") or die $!;
            $spew = 1;
            $count++;

        }

        if ($spew) {
            print $out $_;
        }

        if (/TRANSACTION END/) {
            close($out);
            $spew = 0;
        }
    }
```

This is how the log file looks like

```
*TRANSACTION STARTED* 
[020t CARD INSERTED 
[020tCARD: *************5845 
DATE 01-02-16    TIME 05:45:52 
 05:46:26 GENAC 1 : ARQC 
EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE: NO ARPC 
 05:46:30 GENAC 2 : AAC 
 01 FEB 2016     05:47:41      10160021 

     WITHDRAW 
     FROM XXXXXXXX    ? 
INVALID TRANSCATION ON TERMINAL. 
----------------------- 
[020t 05:47:05 CARD TAKEN 
[020t 05:47:07 TRANSACTION END 
[0r(1)2[000p[040qe1w3h162[020t*742*02/01/2016*05:47* 
     *TRANSACTION STARTED* 
[020t CARD INSERTED 
[020tCARD: *************2584 
DATE 01-02-16    TIME 05:47:27 
 05:48:00 GENAC 1 : ARQC 
 05:48:05 GENAC 2 : TC 
[020t 05:48:16 CARD TAKEN 
[020t 05:48:22 NOTES PRESENTED 0,0,2,0 
 01 FEB 2016     05:48:52      10160021 

     WITHDRAW 
     FROM XXXXXXXX    ? 
AMT   GHC40.00 
[020t 05:48:31 TRANSACTION END 
[0r(1)2[000p[040qe1w3h162[020t*743*02/01/2016*05:57*
```

The Desired output should look like this on each .txt file

```
*TRANSACTION STARTED* 
    [020t CARD INSERTED 
    [020tCARD: *************2584 
    DATE 01-02-16    TIME 05:47:27 
     05:48:00 GENAC 1 : ARQC 
     05:48:05 GENAC 2 : TC 
    [020t 05:48:16 CARD TAKEN 
    [020t 05:48:22 NOTES PRESENTED 0,0,2,0 
     01 FEB 2016     05:48:52      10160021 

         WITHDRAW 
         FROM XXXXXXXX    ? 
    AMT   GHC40.00 
    [020t 05:48:31 TRANSACTION END
```

Comment: This looks oddly familiar. Have you asked something similar before?

Comment: @Sobrique yes  but did not get the answer and the solution i was looking for

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure I've written a solution that does exactly what you request, down to using the same data. But I can't find it any more.

Comment: @Sobrique .why is my code not working?what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is it doing that is undesirable? How is it "not working"?

Comment: @Sobrique And I think I vaguely recall a solution of yours to something just like this.

Comment: @Sobrique this should extracting rang data from a file save each range to a separate file .but the code above only extract every data

Comment: @lord-ivan "Only extracts every data"---what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We set set a flag when we see the start marker, and we turn off the flag when we see the end marker. If the flag is enabled, we print lines. You'll have to adjust the paths to your situation, but this code will definitely create sequential files, one per transaction.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count = 0;
my $spew  = 0;
my $out;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/TRANSACTION STARTED/) {
        open($out, '>', "TRANSACTION$count.txt") or die $!;
        $spew = 1;
        $count++;
    }

    if ($spew) {
        print $out $_;
    }

    if (/TRANSACTION END/) {
        close($out);
        $spew = 0;
    }
}

__DATA__
*TRANSACTION STARTED*
[020t CARD INSERTED
[020tCARD: *************5845
DATE 01-02-16    TIME 05:45:52
 05:46:26 GENAC 1 : ARQC
EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE: NO ARPC
 05:46:30 GENAC 2 : AAC
 01 FEB 2016     05:47:41      10160021

     WITHDRAW
     FROM XXXXXXXX    ?
INVALID TRANSCATION ON TERMINAL.
-----------------------
[020t 05:47:05 CARD TAKEN
[020t 05:47:07 TRANSACTION END
[0r(1)2[000p[040qe1w3h162[020t*742*02/01/2016*05:47*
     *TRANSACTION STARTED*
[020t CARD INSERTED
[020tCARD: *************2584
DATE 01-02-16    TIME 05:47:27
 05:48:00 GENAC 1 : ARQC
 05:48:05 GENAC 2 : TC
[020t 05:48:16 CARD TAKEN
[020t 05:48:22 NOTES PRESENTED 0,0,2,0
 01 FEB 2016     05:48:52      10160021

     WITHDRAW
     FROM XXXXXXXX    ?
AMT   GHC40.00
[020t 05:48:31 TRANSACTION END
[0r(1)2[000p[040qe1w3h162[020t*743*02/01/2016*05:57*
```

Comment: thank you for your loop but it only copies the log file and pasts it in a .txt file. it dose not "create sequential files, one per transaction."

Comment: @lord-ivan Did you even run the code?

Comment: yes i did.i have u can.check from my post

Comment: @lord-ivan What happens when you run the code in my answer? It creates two files named `TRANSACTION0.txt` and `TRANSACTION1.txt`, doesn't it? If that's _not_ what you want, then I didn't understand the question and you'll have to be more clear.

Comment: What is what i want But it only create TRANSACTION0.txt and does not extract   what is with TRANSACTION START'  'TRANSACTION END' but extract the original log file data back to be

Comment: @lord-ivan You are mistaken. It does exactly that.

Comment: i have to code in my post and i will be sending the link to the TRANSACTION0.txt file for u to see  https://www.dropbox.com/s/69atr3x5b5vbz7j/TRANSACTION0.txt?dl=0

Comment: @lord-ivan I'm not going to click on some external link when I've already provided you a working answer based on the question you asked.

Comment: can you have a look at the code i posted

Comment: @lord-ivan It looks fine. I suspect you're either running an old file that you _think_ is the current file, or there's something else going on and you've left out some important details somewhere.

Comment: important details like What?

Comment: @lord-ivan If I knew, I would have told you. But if the code I provided in my answer works correctly, and then you copy it and modify it, and now it _doesn't_ work correctly, I think we can all agree that you've introduced some errors somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Well, as far as I understand, you must open a file when you meet 'TRANSACTION START' and close it when you meet  'TRANSACTION END'. So you should rewrite your loop. Something like that:

```
while (<$fh>) {  
    if (/TRANSACTION STARTED/) {
        $outputfile= "${outdir}TRANSACTION$filenumber";
        open ($ofh, "> $outputfile") or die "Could not open file '$outfile' $!";
        print $ofh $_;     
    } elsif (/TRANSACTION END/) {
        print $ofh $_;     
        close $ofh; 
        $filenumber++;
    } else {
        print $ofh $_;     
    }
}
```

Comment: @jpi It still does not extract the data from the log file. i get only an empty file